# Importing CSV Data to Existing Database

Tags: mysql, csv, dictionary, import

I have a 11 column CSV file that I need to import into a 19 column Database. How can I map the fields that the CSV has to import into the Database correctly?

Comment: Can you expand your question a bit? What kind of database, what tool are you using to do it, etc.? I.e. are you writing a Python script to process the CSV and push it into the database with the Python bindings? Or are you trying to export from Excel and into Access? Without knowing that, it'll be hard to give a good answer.

Comment: MySQL database, came straight to me as a CSV. It's a one time import.

Comment: What kind of programming tools do you have on your system? And how much programming experience do you have?

Comment: Mostly code in PHP. Basic web programming tools.

Comment: I'd recommend using PHPMyAdmin and doing the import using that tool, then.  It's easy to install, configure, and do pretty much everything on your database.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin doesn't like the fact that my columns don't match up. I can't just import it.

Comment: Ouch.  If your columns don't match up, then you have the problem of matching them up... that's a whole different story b/c you have to ask the question, "How do I know which column goes to which column?"

Comment: @Nicole, I'd recommend following Jose's answer below if you're not comfortable dealing with the text yourself. Your other option is doing some processing of the CSV text first to map it to the columns (in the past I've usually written regular expression-based handlers for this kind of thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to do so is creating a table with the same CVS structure. After use [load data in file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to import the CVS to database you can create a simple insert select script to migrate the data from one table to another.

Answer (score 1):

See the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) about the insert SQL command. The MySQL Workbench makes it easier to insert a CSV into a MySQL database.

Comment: agreed, use MYSQL workbench to make life easier. It reverse engineers it for you, help you create schema e.t.c..